# sublime text syntax highlight plugin - coloring function name

Tags: sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting, textmate

i am trying to make sublime text plugin for syntax highlighting of a programming language called "e verification language":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28verification_language%29

function definition in this language:

`function_name (name_1: type_1, name_2: type_2, ...) : return_type is {
     function body
}`

for example:

```
function_name(num1: int, num2: real) : int is { ...
```

input parameters and return value are optional.

no input parameters, no return value, no both:

```
function_name() : int is { ...
function_name(num1: int, num2: real) is { ...
function_name() is { ...
```

i want to color function name, and keep the rest of the keywords in the line also colored if needed ("int" and "real" are types, "is" is a syntax keyword, ":" should also be colored if present).

i tried  using "captures" block in the plugin tmLanguage file. succeeded coloring functions name, but because the line is being recognized by the "is" at the end, everything in between is not highlighted.
i am capturing 4 things in the line: function name, "(", ")", "is"

code used:

```
        <dict>
            <key>captures</key>
            <dict>
                <key>1</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>entity.name.function</string>
                </dict>
                <key>2</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>keyword.language</string>
                </dict>
                <key>3</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>keyword.language</string>
                </dict>
                <key>4</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>keyword.language</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>match</key>
            <string>^\s*(\b[^\s]+)\s*(\()\s*.*\s*(\))\s*:*\s*.*\s+(is)\b</string>
        </dict>
```

i add photos of functions with my capture block (blue function name), and without (white name, green "int" and "real"). is there any way to combine, so that all what is needed will be colored?

thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to **nest** the syntax higlighting using `repository`

I encourage you to work with .YAML-tmLanguage files (easier to read) that you can easily convert to .tmLanguage using [PackageDev](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageDev)

1. **Create a .YAML-tmLanguage syntax file suiting your syntax**

Here is the stripped file for C language (name it `myc.YAML-tmLanguage` in Packages/User):

```
fileTypes: [myc, myh]
scopeName: source.myc
name: myc

patterns:
  - match: \b(for|if)\b
    name: keyword.control.c

  - match: \b(int)\b
    name: storage.type.c

  - include: '#block'

  - begin: "(?x)\n    \t\t(?:  ^                                 # begin-of-line\n \
      \   \t\t  |\n    \t\t     (?: (?= \\s )           (?<!else|new|return) (?<=\\\
      w)      #  or word + space before name\n    \t\t       | (?= \\s*[A-Za-z_] ) (?<!&&)\
      \       (?<=[*&>])   #  or type modifier before name\n    \t\t     )\n    \t\t\
      )\n    \t\t(\\s*) (?!(while|for|do|if|else|switch|catch|enumerate|return|r?iterate)\\\
      s*\\()\n    \t\t(\n    \t\t\t(?: [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*+ | :: )++ |          \
      \        # actual name\n    \t\t\t(?: (?<=operator) (?: [-*&<>=+!]+ | \\(\\) |\
      \ \\[\\] ) )  # if it is a C++ operator\n    \t\t)\n    \t\t \\s*(?=\\()"
    beginCaptures:
      '1':
        name: punctuation.whitespace.function.leading.c
      '3':
        name: entity.name.function.c
      '4':
        name: punctuation.definition.parameters.c
    end: (?<=\})|(?=#)|(;)
    name: meta.function.c
    patterns:
    - include: '#parens'
    - include: '#block'

repository:
  block:
    begin: \{
    end: \}
    name: meta.block.c
    patterns:
    - include: '#block_innards'

  parens:
    begin: \(
    end: \)
    name: meta.parens.c
    patterns:
    - include: $self

  block_innards:
    patterns:
    - include: '#block'
    - include: $self

    - captures:
        '1':
          name: punctuation.whitespace.function-call.leading.c
        '2':
          name: support.function.any-method.c
        '3':
          name: punctuation.definition.parameters.c
      match: "(?x) (?: (?= \\s )  (?:(?<=else|new|return) | (?<!\\w)) (\\s+))?\n\t\
        \t\t(\\b\n\t\t\t\t(?!(while|for|do|if|else|switch|catch|enumerate|return|r?iterate)\\\
        s*\\()(?:(?!NS)[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*+\\b | :: )++                  # actual\
        \ name\n\t\t\t)\n\t\t\t \\s*(\\()"
      name: meta.function-call.c
```

2. **Convert it to .tmLanguage file**

After installing PackageDev you can now **convert it to PLIST syntax** (Ctrl+Shift+P > YAML to PLIST) and save it under `myc.tmLanguage`.

3. **Test syntax highlighting in Sublime Text**

Here is a sample `test.myc` file using calls in blocks and your requested function structure func(int <...>, int <...>):

```
int prime(int n, int n);
int main()
{
    for(i=2; i<=n/2; ++i)
    {
        if (prime(i)!=0)
        {
            test(int k, int n);
            if ( prime(n-i)!=0)
            {
                printf("%d = %d + %d\n", n, i, n-i);
                flag=1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here you have the [syntax highlighting in ST3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdyTO.png). Hope you can get it to work for e (verification language) ...